# Angular: wait for the return of one observable to initiate the other

Tags: angular, typescript, http, asynchronous

My business scenario is like this:
I first issue a HTTP request to the token() endpoint in the WebAPI to get an auth token (this happens in the app.component.ts). Then I have a token-interceptor module to append the token to the HTTP headers of the subsequent requests.

Then I have a getLanguages() endpoint in the WebAPI, and this gets called within my header component - header.component.ts. So this call goes through the HTTP interceptor and try to append the token generated to the request header, but it fails because the token() endpoint has not returned yet, so the getLanguages() endpoint is not authenticated.

I'm obviously missing something here. I've read about `ReplaySubject` but I'm not sure how to put everything together.

Here's my current code.

### app.component.html:

```
<app-header>
</app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer>
</app-footer>
```

### auth.service.ts:

```
 authenticateClient(){

let body = new HttpParams()
  .set('client_id', AppConst.GLOBAL.auth.client_id)
  .set('grant_type', AppConst.GLOBAL.auth.grant_type)
  .set('scope', AppConst.GLOBAL.auth.scope);

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};

let authGatewayUrl: string = AppConst.GLOBAL.authApiUrl + window.location.search;

return this.http.post(authGatewayUrl, body.toString(), httpOptions)
          .pipe(map((res: any) => this.token = res), catchError(this.handleErrorObservable));
      }

  getToken(): Token {
    return this.token;
  }
```

### app.component.ts:

```
token: Token;

 ngOnInit() {
// get the authentication token and store it for usage in subsequent API calls.
this.authService.authenticateClient().subscribe(
  obj => this.token = obj as Token,
  err => alert(err)
  );
  }
```

### app.service.ts:

```
  getLanguages() {
 return this.http.get(this.localeApiUrl)
  .pipe(map((res: any) => this.languages = res), catchError(this.handleErrorObservable));
  }
```

### header.component.ts:

```
   constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    this.appService.getLanguages().subscribe(obj => this.languages = obj);

  };
```

### http-interceptor.ts:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
// exclude the token API endpoint from the interception
const loginUrl: string = AppConst.GLOBAL.authApiUrl;

if (req.url.search(loginUrl) === -1) {
  // Get the auth token from the service.
  const authToken = this.auth.getToken();

  //// Clone the request and set the new header in one step.
  req = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: authToken.access_token } });
}

//// send cloned request with header to the next handler.
return next.handle(req);
 }
```

Comment: You could use the rxJs `switchMap` to do that

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that too. But I'm note sure how it fits in. Can you perhaps give an example?

Comment: The simplest way in your case is to use a `BehaviorSubject` to handle this. In your authentication service you can add `authenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)`. You can then pass new value to your BehaviorSubject with `next()` method like : `this.authenticated$.next(true)`. You will then be able to use it in every component you inject the authentication service => `this.authService.authenticated$.subscribe(authentiicated => // ToDO if authenticated = true)`. BehaviorSubject are the perfect fit for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You could save your token info in a `BehaviorSubject` inside the AuthService.

Then trigger `.next(token)` when `authenticateClient()` success.

In the `header.component` so you could do.

```
  readonly languages$ = this.authService.token$.pipe(
    first(!!token), // or filter, depends on your application logic
    switchMap(() => this.appService.getLanguages(),
  );

  this.languages$.subscribe(obj => this.languages = obj);
```

In the code above you're creating a new Observable from authService, when someone trigger `next` on the token `BehaviorSubject`, this observable checks if token is defined and if it is, you could call your internal API.

This is a way, but I think there are other solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Answer (score -4):

You can use Promise for the same.

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Async Work Complete");
  if (error) {
    reject();
  } else {
    resolve();
  }
}, 1000);

});
```